# jQuery AJAX -> get ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#writeReview').click(function(){
        var id =  $('.ajaxsend').attr('id');
        var link = 'writereview/' + id;
        console.log(id);
        console.log('In the click');
    })

    $('.login_form').on('submit', function(e) {
        $.post( 'writereview/' , $(this).serialize(), function(response) {
            $("#login_message").html( response );
        });
        // disable default action
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

How can I get the var link in the HREF for the post? The link starts always with `writereview/` and then an ID. Anyone that can help me?

Comment: well, you can't, since it is defined in a different scope. you'll have to define said var in the submit event, or make it available to both scopes by defining it in a scope that both have access to.

Comment: can you share the relevant html

Comment: I think you can var id =  $('.ajaxsend').attr('id');
        var link = 'writereview/' + id;  on submit

Comment: `$.post( 'writereview/'+$('.ajaxsend').attr('id'),...)` ???

Comment: How are `#writeReview` and `.login_form` related? When are the events triggered?

Comment: `$('.ajaxsend').attr('id')` would always get the first elements ID (if there are more than one) so why not just get it in the submit handler as well ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the variables in the right scope (so outside any functions) like this:

```
var id;
var link;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#writeReview').click(function () {
        id = $('.ajaxsend').attr('id');
        link = 'writereview/' + id;
        console.log(id);
        console.log('In the click');
    })

    $('.login_form').on('submit', function (e) {
        if (!link) 
            return;

        $.post(link, $(this).serialize(), function (response) {
            $("#login_message").html(response);

        });
        // disable default action
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

So if you click the `#writeReview` button first and then do the submit it should work.

As long as the variables are defined in the right scope it is fine (so you could place them, as A. Wolff mentioned inside the document ready)

Comment: Okay, i get the link, i receive the ID, but what i dont get: if i use the var link, it wont work good. if i use the link manually instead of the var link, it works good. Anyone an idea? $.post(link, $(this).serialize(), function (response) {

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.login_form').on('submit', function(e) {
       var id =  $('.ajaxsend').attr('id');
        var link = 'writereview/' + id;
    $.post( 'writereview/'+link , $(this).serialize(), function(response) {
        $("#login_message").html( response );

    });
        // disable default action
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

Or like this(make link outside the function):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var link='';
    $('#writeReview').click(function(){
        var id =  $('.ajaxsend').attr('id');
        link = 'writereview/' + id;
        console.log(id);
        console.log('In the click');
    })

    $('.login_form').on('submit', function(e) {
        $.post( 'writereview/'+link , $(this).serialize(), function(response) {
            $("#login_message").html( response );
        });
        // disable default action
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```